# ASP.Net Ajax ComboBox in ModalPopup

Tags: asp.net, ajax, combobox, modalpopupextender

I have a combo box inside a ModalPopupExtender and when the popup is showed the list of items is not located under the text box but is offset to the right.
my code is:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true">
        <Services>
        </Services>
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JavaScript/ScriptManager.js" />
        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="dialog" runat="server"> 
        <div id="dialogContents"> 
            <asp:ComboBox ID="DropDownListMailTos" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                DropDownStyle="DropDown" Width="90%" RenderMode="Block"> 
                <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" /> 
                <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" /> 
                <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" /> 
            </asp:ComboBox> 
            <br /> 
            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" Text="OK" runat="server" /> 
        </div> 
    </asp:Panel> 

    <asp:Button ID="btnShow" Text="Open Dialog" runat="server" /> 

    <asp:ModalPopupExtender 
        TargetControlID="btnShow" 
        PopupControlID="dialog" 
        OkControlID="btnOK" 
        DropShadow="true" 
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
        runat="server" /> 
</div>
```

i tried few solutions found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/peterblum/archive/2011/09/16/more-with-ajax-control-toolkit-s-combobox-and-modalpopupextender.aspx) and [here](http://vincexu.blogspot.com/2009/05/ajaxcontroltoolkit-combobox-not.html)

but no luck there.
What can i do about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the only problem here is that the `ModalPopup` is clashing with the default styling of the `ComboBox`.  You just need to play around with the CSS class that's applied to the `ListItem`s in the `ComboBox` to get them to show up right.  Add the following code to your CSS for that page (tested in IE9, Chrome, and FireFox) and you should be good:

```
.ajax__combobox_itemlist
{
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

For more information, see the section on "Combo Box Theming" at the bottom of the [documentation page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx).